# Should generic or specialized exceptions be thrown in the JNI interface?

Tags: java, c++, exception, java-native-interface

### Scenario

A Java codebase uses a C++ library. A JNI interface is implemented in order to have an API to access native methods using Java calls.

The way this is done up until now, is by having a function Java side:

```
private static native void useFancyNativeFunction() throws SomeCustomException;
```

And the corresponding method in the JNI header file includes error handling which in turn throws the Java exception when needed:

```
try
{
    // do amazing C++ things
}
catch ( const std::runtime_error& e )
{
    jclass Exception = env->FindClass( "util/somestuff/SomeCustomException" );
    env->ThrowNew( Exception, e.what() );
}
```

This means, in case a runtime exception is thrown in a specific chunk of our native code, a custom Java exception is then thrown and handled in our application encapsuled by the JVM.

### Question

This brought up an interesting discussion that has yet to be solved:

Throwing a custom exception in this context means we create a dependency between the JNI interface implementation and our specific Java codebase. An alternative is throwing generic Java exceptions natively, then catch them via Java code and then throw a specialized exception.

So in the given scenario there are two options:

1. Throw specialized custom Java exception natively:

```
// Java caller
try
{
    useFancyNativeFunction();
}
catch( SomeCustomException e )
{
    // treat custom exception directly here
}

// Java native call
private static native void useFancyNativeFunction() throws SomeCustomException;

// C++ JNI header
try
{
    // do amazing C++ things
}
catch ( const std::runtime_error& e )
{
    jclass Exception = env->FindClass( "util/somestuff/SomeCustomException" );
    env->ThrowNew( Exception, e.what() );
}
```

2. Throw generic Java exception natively, catch it in Java class, rethrow as specialized exception:

```
// Java caller
try
{
    useFancyNativeFunction();
}
catch( RuntimeException e )
{
    // catch generic, throw specialized, handle elsewhere
    throw new SomeCustomException( e.getMessage() );
}

// Java native call
private static native void useFancyNativeFunction() throws RuntimeException;

// C++ JNI header
try
{
    // do amazing C++ things
}
catch ( const std::runtime_error& e )
{
    jclass Exception = env->FindClass( "java/lang/RuntimeException" );
    env->ThrowNew( Exception, e.what() );
}
```

Which is preferred and why?

### Additional information

- In our case there is no downside to either version, because there is only one Java codebase and only one C++ codebase. The JNI interface needs not to be reused.
- The dependency exists only in the interface itself, not in the library. The latter is being reused by us, however without Java being involved.
- It is not likely that either option will have significant consequences for us. I am merely asking out of interest.

Comment: "create a dependency between the JNI interface implementation and our specific Java codebase" It doesn't necessarily make it the right thing to do but the JNI I maintain (10 years old) and the corresponding Java code are inextricably linked. I would always advise throwing a specific exception.

Comment: This is my feeling as well so far, however there are reasons for and against. *E.g.* the path to the exception class from native point of view is merely a string and therefore a potential source of error. The path for generic exceptions is always the same. I am looking for more reasons and/or best practice suggestions.

Comment: @Bathsheba do you have a reason for your preference by any chance?

Comment: It makes the JNI behave much more like regular Java code. Another approach I guess would be to "stub out" all native functions on the Java side, catch generic exception thrown from the JNI then rethrow them as a specific exception type. Funny, I've just realised you have that as an option. I don't do this since I'm already having to call into the Java code.

Comment: Yes exactly, your alternative is option 2. in my post. The only reason I see so far is library (and JNI) reuse in a different Java codebase. Because in this case there is a requirement toward the Java codebase to correctly implement the custom exception. Otherwise the JNI interface will attempt throwing an exception that does not exist, as it looks for it by classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main question is whether you want to re-use the native library on its own, or always bundle it with a Java wrapper.

Very often, a Java wrapper makes sense on its own, independent of the exceptions issue, it makes the native functionality look more Java-like.

### Role of the exception object

An exception object is meant to communicate to a caller (somewhere up the call stack, where the exception is caught) the reason why some method call failed. To typical code, that reason is irrelevant (1), it's enough to know about the failure and be able to produce a sensible log entry plus a message to the user.

### Communicating failure from native code

You chose to communicate failure from native code by having the C++ top layer create and throw Java exceptions, and that creates a dependency to the Java exception system and the specific exception class you chose to use.

I see a few  options:

- Use a Java standard exception like `RuntimeException`. We can trust that it will always exist, so that dependency that will not create any problems.
- Use your own exception type like `MyWonderfulLibraryException`. I'd recommend against such a naming. This doesn't describe a reason for failure but the location of the failure. You have to make sure that the exception class is available in your Java wrapper library.
- Use your own exception type like `NativeCppException`. Technically, it's the same as
  the previous choice, but IMHO better describes the failure reason as something that cannot appropriately be described inside the Java computation model.
- Communicate failure from native code without creating a Java exception, e.g. by special failure return values. That might be easier (and more performant, and creating less code dependencies) than your current approach.

### Communicating failure to user code

User code should see an exception in case of failure, one that describes the reason of the failure (mainly for logging purposes).

In your case, the reason is hidden somewhere inside the text coming from the C++ `runtime_error`. You might be tempted to map that into different appropriate Java exception types, but "You Ain't Gonna Need It (YAGNI)".

My preferred choice would be something like `NativeCppException`, summarizing everything that can happen in the C++ world. Some caller might be brave enough to catch such an exception, probably only if he has a non-native alternative available.

**(Footnote 1)**

I know that there are diverging opinions on the importance of individual exception types, but I have yet to find a convincing argument to warrant the exceedingly complex exception type hierarchies often seen in the wild.

Exception types are created to be used by some part of your code, otherwise it's a classical YAGNI case.

Regarding failure of internal calls, methods typically fall into three categories:

1. Method does not have a fallback strategy, so in case of some internal failure, the whole method fails. Typically, these methods let exceptions ripple through without intervening.
2. Method has a fallback strategy, allowing to succeed even after failure of some internal calls, typically by retrying, or by switching to an alternative path of execution. If such a fallback strategy exists, it typically makes sense to use it, independent of the failure reason. These methods catch all exceptions arising within specific blocks, and then activate the fallback, independent of the failure reason.
3. Method has a fallback strategy that can only be applied in specific cases, and the cases can be distinguished by the exception type. These methods catch only some specific exception types, and then activate the appropriate fallback.

- The vast majority of methods falls into the first category (or should fall into the category, weren't they over-engineered).
- For a few methods, developers create fallback strategies. Most often it doesn't harm to try that strategy not only for specific failures, but for any failure.
- In a very small percentage of cases, the failure reason matters for selecting a fallback that would otherwise be inappropriate, e.g. if the database tells me by means of an exception that my password has expired, the code can then redirect me to the password-renewal procedure and then continue (a somewhat contrived example).

The actual exception type only matters in the third method type, and I bet only a very small percentage of exception types ever gets used this way, so we have a classical case of YAGNI.

Comment: *Communicate failure from native code without creating a Java exception, e.g. by special failure return values. That might be easier (and more performant, and creating less code dependencies) than your current approach.* That's what I do with my JNI code, for those very reasons - and another huge one:  the JNI interface is actually a C interface and not C++. And C doesn't throw exceptions. (I also try to absolutely minimize the amount of native code - if the native code logically creates a Java object, I write a Java wrapper method to create an empty object and pass it to the native code.)

Comment: @AndrewHenle this approach does not present a viable option for us. There are hundreds of native functions accessed, some of which are operating on pointers, however many of which are returning values of various types. I see no benefit in trying to define an error-state object for each of those types and return it and there is not enough advantage to justify such a large refactoring. This is probably an option to consider when designing a new project using JNI.

Comment: @AndrewHenle *the JNI interface is actually a C interface and not C++. And C doesn't throw exceptions.* It doesn't have to though. The described code instructs the bound JVM instance to throw an exception of a specific type with specific constructor parameters - which does work.

Comment: Ralf Kleberhoff Thank you for the detailled answer.